# Reactivity issues with Vue 3 + Typescript + Vuex + DevExtreme

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm implementing a component that works as a search engine, that is, for each character I insert in the input, a request must be made to the back and the results must be updated. I'm implementing it with an autocomplete and the result would be the one I'm going to show below:

[image]

I got this image by mocking the object returned by the back. If I do the same process from the vuex module, I don't get results.

The steps I have followed are as follows. First I implemented the Vuex module as follows:

```
export type State = {
    results: any[]
}

const state: State = {
    results: [],
}

const mutations: MutationTree<State> = {
    SET_RESULTS(state: any, payload: any) {
        state.results = payload.resultsByType;
        console.log(state.results)
    }
}

const actions: ActionTree<State, any> = {
    async getResults({ commit }: any, query: string) {
        await itiHttpService.get(API.documents + '/search/' + query, null, false).then((res: any) => {
            commit('SET_RESULTS', res);
        });
    },
}

const getters: GetterTree<State, any> = {
    results: (state: any) => state.results,
}

const searchModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}

export default searchModule;
```

The console.log I have set on the mutation gives the following result per console:

[image]

```
setup(){ 
...
let resultsValue: ResultFilterDto[] = [];
const results = computed(() => { return store.state['searchModule'].results });

function valueChangedGetResults(e: any) {
    var textWrited = e.value;
    if (textWrited !== null && textWrited !== undefined && textWrited.length >= minQueryLength) {
        store.dispatch('searchModule/getResults', textWrited);
    }
}

watch(
    results,
    () => {
        resultsValue = results.value;
        console.log(resultsValue);
        }
);
        
...
```

From my component I have created a computed property to access the state information of my store and then I have created a watch to observe the changes that occur. I also have the valueChangedGetResult method where the dispatch is done to query the back every time I type a word longer than 3 characters. The query to the back is done properly and the information is updated in resultsValue because it gets all the information from the console.

[image]

The code in my html, is as follows.

[image]

The way I have explained the autocomplete does not work and does not show any result, however, if I make a mock of the object like the following and put in the data-source of the HTML the variable test, it works. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much!

```
var test: any = [{
            key: 'Inbox',
            items: [{
                id: 17,
                name: "test1.txt",
                extension: null,
                summary: "Name: test1.txt\tInboxName: Inbox 1\t",
                highLigths: "Name: <span style='font-weight:bold'>test</span>1.txt  \r\n",
                creationDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                inboxName: "Inbox 1",
                inboxId: 1,
                folderId: 0,
                folderName: null,
                categoryId: 0,
                categoryName: null,
                typeId: 0,
                typeName: null,
                subTypeId: 0,
                subTypeName: null
            },
            {
                id: 17,
                name: "test1.txt",
                extension: null,
                summary: "Name: test1.txt\tInboxName: Inbox 1\t",
                highLigths: "Name: <span style='font-weight:bold'>test</span>1.txt  \r\n",
                creationDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                inboxName: "Inbox 1",
                inboxId: 1,
                folderId: 0,
                folderName: null,
                categoryId: 0,
                categoryName: null,
                typeId: 0,
                typeName: null,
                subTypeId: 0,
                subTypeName: null
            }
            ]
        }, {
            key: 'Archive',
            items: [{
                id: 17,
                name: "test1.txt",
                extension: null,
                summary: "Name: test1.txt\tInboxName: Inbox 1\t",
                highLigths: "Name: <span style='font-weight:bold'>test</span>1.txt  \r\n",
                creationDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                inboxName: "Inbox 1",
                inboxId: 1,
                folderId: 0,
                folderName: null,
                categoryId: 0,
                categoryName: null,
                typeId: 0,
                typeName: null,
                subTypeId: 0,
                subTypeName: null
            }]
        }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is you are using `resultsValue` variable inside template, but it is not reactive...it is just plain array. Changing it doesn't re-render the template...

You can fix it by `let resultsValue = ref<ResultFilterDto[]>([]);` (don't forget to import `ref` from `vue`) and changing assignment to `resultsValue.value = results.value`

**BUT** you don't need `resultsValue` variable at all. You already have a reactive `computed` value `results`. So just remove `resultsValue` from your code and use `results` instead in the template....

```js
setup(){ 

  const results = computed(() => { return store.state['searchModule'].results });

  function valueChangedGetResults(e: any) {
    var textWrited = e.value;
    if (textWrited !== null && textWrited !== undefined && textWrited.length >= minQueryLength) {
        store.dispatch('searchModule/getResults', textWrited);
    }
  }

  return {
    results
  }     
}
```